# Collection modified error when adding implicit style from code to Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, styles, implicit, xamarin.forms

### Background

With Xamarin.Forms 1.3 implicit styles were introduced (jippie). With a Portable Class Library (PCL) as base for your Xamarin.Forms project you can init Application.Current.Resources and add new styles to the collection. I can however not get this working without run time exception.

### Collection was modified error

In my App.cs in the Xamarin.Forms PCL project, I've tried adding this code either in the beginning or end as [documented](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/):

```
        if (Current.Resources == null)
        {
            Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        }

        Current.Resources.Add(
            new Style(typeof(Label))
                {
                    BaseResourceKey = Device.Styles.BodyStyleKey,
                    Setters =
                        {
                            new Setter
                                {
                                    Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
                                    Value = Color.White
                                }
                        }
                });
```

Trying to run this on either Windows Phone or Android gived the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. at [...] Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnResourcesChanged(Object sender, ResourcesChangedEventArgs e) at Xamarin.Forms.MergedResourceDictionary...

I've tried this with Xamarin.Forms 1.3 and the latest 1.3.2.6299-pre. No luck.
Anyone seen it, or gotten implicit styles working themselves?